# Android theming Actionbar tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-theme, android-tabs, android-style-tabhost

I want to customize my tab like this [image: custom tab style]

i.e a selected tab will have a white background while a unselected tab will have a green background.

Till now I am able to achieve

[image: what I have done]

to achieve this I am doing the following as my style:-

```
<resources>
    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/sa_green</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/stacked_green</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/sa_green</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**color.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="sa_green">#14a804</color>
    <color name="stacked_green">#118504</color>
    <color name="accent_green">#97e08f</color>
</resources>
```

How to remove the blue indicator and change the background on the basis of which tab is selected?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs

Comment: @2Dee I have seen that example but was unable to implement it properly. Can you point me to any working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a selector xml, instead of just @color/sa_green. The selector will tell the tab, according to its state, what color to use.

You can go as simple as that:

drawable/tab_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false"
      android:background="@color/green" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Then you just have to put

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
```

in your theme

And declare in your style ActionBar, something like this:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_selector</item>
</style>
```

And that should be it